# Laravel nested groupBy is returning an unchanged array

Tags: php, laravel

I have a collection of objects that look like the following:

```
user: {
  name: userName,
  region: userRegion,
  role: userRole
}
```

Each of these objects have already been grouped according to their regions, however I would like to further group them (within the region collections) based on their role.

I have tried doing this:

```
$Levels = $Regions->each(function ($item, $key) {
    return $item->groupBy(function ($item, $key) {
        return $item['Owner']['role'];
    });
});
```

However it returns the original, region-grouped collections, which looks like this:

```
EU => collection {
    #items: array: 10 [
        0 => array: 3,
        1 => array: 3...
    ]
}
```

Ideally I'd end up with a result like:

```
EU {
    role1: array,
    role2: array...
}
```

Any direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this problem by changing the `each` method to `map` method.